# mysql hibernate createSQLQuery timestamp range result null

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, datetime

the mysql query string is

```
SELECT d.sn,
       CONVERT(AVG(dd.light), SIGNED) as light,
       CONVERT(MAX(dd.light), SIGNED) as hlight,
       CONVERT(MIN(dd.light), SIGNED) as llight,
       CONVERT(AVG(dd.wetness), SIGNED) as dwetness,
       CONVERT(MAX(dd.wetness), SIGNED) as hdwetness,
       CONVERT(MIN(dd.wetness), SIGNED) as ldwetness,
       CONVERT(AVG(dd.temp), SIGNED) as temp,
       CONVERT(MAX(dd.temp), SIGNED) as htemp,
       CONVERT(MIN(dd.temp), SIGNED) as ltemp
  from device_data dd, device d
 where d.id = dd.device_id
   and dd.device_id = 396
   and dd.wetness <= 100
   and dd. timestamp >= '2016-10-24 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY d.id
```

when i use `navicat`  it return right value, but when i use
`SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(senseDataSql);`

it returns null, I do not known why?

Comment: not null. if i remove the timestamp,sqlquery can return value

Comment: @frankin try to compare the date part using `SimpleDateFormat` like   this `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` and then in query `and to_char(dd.timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd') >= '" + sdf.format('2016-10-24') + "'`

Comment: See the example https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/